# I have create this toggle menu for mobile device using javascript but this is not working

Tags: javascript

I have create this toggle menu for mobile device using javascript but this is not working

```js
const selectElement = (s) => document.querySelector(s);
selectElement(s: '.open').addEventListener('click', () => {
    selectElement(s:'nav-list').classList.add('active');
});
selectElement(s:'.close').addEventListener('click', () => {
    selectElement(s:'nav-list').classList.remove(tokens:'active');
});
```

Comment: We also need to see your HTML and CSS, the problem might be there instead of the Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some extra colons in your query parameters.  You don't need the `s:` unless you're passing in the parameters as an object.

You can either remove the extra object notation:

```js
const selectElement = (s) => document.querySelector(s);
selectElement('.open').addEventListener('click', () => {
    selectElement('nav-list').classList.add('active');
});
selectElement(close').addEventListener('click', () => {
    selectElement('nav-list').classList.remove('active');
});
```

or add brackets around the function `selectElement`'s parameter and turn it into object destructuring:

```js
const selectElement = ({ s }) => document.querySelector(s);
selectElement({ s: '.open' }).addEventListener('click', () => {
    selectElement({ s: 'nav-list' }).classList.add('active');
});
selectElement({ s: '.close' }).addEventListener('click', () => {
    selectElement({ s: 'nav-list' }).classList.remove('active');
});
```

I'd recommend the first option as using objects for function parameters only really helps when you have multiple parameters that you're trying to keep track of.

In either case you'd want to remove `tokens:` from the `classList.remove()` function

Answer (score 0):

```
const selectElement = (s) => document.querySelector(s);
selectElement('.open').addEventListener('click',selectElement('nav-list').classList.add('active'));
selectElement(close').addEventListener('click',selectElement('nav-list').classList.remove('active'));
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck